# Group of size 10 containing an element of order 5.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The above question is a review question for a test. My first thought was $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, but I don't think this contains an element of order 5. Would 2 be an element of order 5? What is a group of size 10 containing an element of order 5? Is there a good way of approaching problems like this?

Comment: Yes, $2$ has order $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The title is not a question. What is the question exactly?

Comment: Remark: You can check all groups of small orders [on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups).

Answer (score 4):

In fact, per [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), if a prime $p$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.  $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ certainly works, with $2$ having order $5$.

Furthermore, it's worth noting that cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have the property that there exists exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for *every* $d|n$.  Because [subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic), this implies that we can find an element of order $d$ for every such $d$ (sometimes more than one--e.g. every non-identity element of a prime-order subgroup generates that subgroup).